# PostgreSQL JDBC query slow, direct on database fast

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc

I'm having an interesting issue with Spring JDBC. I have a simple SELECT query which just selects a single row from the database by its identifier. When I run this query through PgAdmin raw on the database it returns in approximately 500ms. When I run it through my Java stack it takes a full 20 *seconds*, and it does not get faster on subsequent runs.

This is the last layer of my code that hangs:

```
return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(QUERY_SINGLE_COMPONENT, queryArguments, new ComponentRowMapper());
```

(my jdbcTemplate is a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate). I have run VisualVM on my code during this execution:

[image: jvisualvm profile]

the PostgreSQL driver readMore is taking essentially all of the time. I'm using the PostgreSQL driver 42.0.0 but I tried updating to the latest version which did not help.

Other IDs in this same query return just fine, other queries I'm making through this same codebase work just fine. Its been driving me crazy for days and would appreciate any insight!

EDIT: I've managed to isolate the issue to our schema search path. We use a test schema to stage database changes. When test is in the schema search path it is slow, when test is removed it is fast. In both cases it is still slower than when I run it in PgAdmin by an order of magnitude.

Comment: Just a wild guess... but perhaps you are connection pooling and the process is waiting for a connection lock to become available? Do you have any other processes that might be "hanging on" to a connection for too long?

Comment: We are using connection pooling, I'd be suspicious about that explanation just because it's very consistently just this one query, and it is always 20-30 seconds

Comment: Is this happening live? or in a test scenario? in a test scenario I'd expect to see it repeated. Not in a live scenario. As I said initially, it's a guess and likely not the cause... but worth a mention just in case

Comment: This happens live, both on my local instance and on the testing server. It's very very consistent. Our in-house PostgreSQL and JDBC experts are stumped as well, which is why I turned to the internet

Comment: I think you'll need to share `QUERY_SINGLE_COMPONENT` if you want more help. And perhaps anything interesting about the rows returned (eg large blobs). And perhaps `ComponentRowMapper`

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, query is 8 times slower with JDBC. Did you figure this out?

Comment: Have you checked that the SQL being sent by spring is what you expect? You should be able to enable debug/trace logs to see the raw SQL being sent to postgres